# Highcharts: How to make curve start outside of the visible view horizontally?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to figure out how to make curve come in outside of the visible view of highcharts.. I got fiddle where curve(defined as *area*) is appearing from the bottom [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F9cq6/) but with my case I have 6 months visible all the time using `tickInterval: 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000` and normal number values at yAxis.

When I have data only for example 1 month which point is middle of the chart I would like there to be more than just one point by making curve appearing in from left hand side of curve aligned to be straight line with same height than current data point is?

If possible, point should be set outside of the visible view so I cant hover on it or select it ( because I want there to be tooltip for real points ).

Reason why I want to make this; is to make empty curve look better, I could just set one point like 30 to left most month but that would not be valid to my case since it is selectable, it has marker and tooltip. (Wrong data for user) Solution where I can add data point to left most month and disable its marker and tooltip could also be valid if thats the only way to achieve this? (note: I want to keep markers and tooltip for rest of the points. ) Any help?

Thnx in advance!

Comment: Did you link the wrong fiddle? The one you linked doesn't show your curve, tickInterval, etc.

Comment: Yea, I didnt link mine curve since its data is dynamically loaded so I didnt go through trouble of extracting it here, since I already described the relevant parts, or was there something that you didnt understand? In a nutshell: same than that fiddle but line should appear from the left , outside the visible view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I guess I had bad day earlier - i managed to solve this by using `min` and `max` values of `xAxis` and also assigning dummy values to both sides of curve (*generated at server side*) which will be left outside of visible view.

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bcD28/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use reversed parameter for xAxis http://jsfiddle.net/w9kED/

```
 reversed:true
```

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.reversed